# Reversing the direction of current in an inductor

Tags: inductor

Would it be safe to instantly reverse the direction of current in an inductor? The flow of current through it is controlled by MOSFETs. 
In case you're wondering, it's for a 1cm long electromagnet with approximately 100 coils with 2-4 amps and a cross sectional area of only 1cm2. Testing this out of curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember the defining equation for an inductor:

$$V = L \frac{di}{dt}$$

"Instantly" reversing the direction of current implies \$\frac{di}{dt} = \infty\$ and therefore

$$V=\infty$$

Infinite voltage is non-trivial to deal with.

You should carefully think through your proposed method for instantly reversing current through an inductor. You will find that it is very difficult to accomplish (in the non-ideal world of real life, *impossible* would be the appropriate term).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can try to reverse the current, but it's going to take a while and could produce a very large amount of back EMF. Inductors resist changes in the flow of current by generating an opposing voltage, after all.